# Tooltip on hover on element

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I was following [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_bottom) for a tooltip on hover. I am unable to do so when I have a class already assigned to the element tag `<i>`. I found out I can assign 2 classes to the same element by having them separated by space. But, the icon disappears if I have class tooltip.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<td>
  <i class="material-icons tooltip" ng-click="view(application._id)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
    receipt
  </i>
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <i class="material-icons" ng-click='edit(application._id)' style="color:red">
    edit
  </i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <i class="material-icons" ng-click="remove(application._id)" style="color:red">
    delete
  </i>
</td>
```

How can I have a tooltip with hover on these icons `<i class="material-icons">`? In my css, tooltip is `visibility: hidden;` . is it because of this? how to correct it?

**Edit** - I have added the style-sheet which If i include, the icon is invisible.

I have created a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/TTrain/r5hhkwLb/

Comment: As two different solutions are all working I suppose that your problem is somewhere in some different code. Could you please look if you set background and foreground color of the icons to the same value? If the problem only occurs on the first, this may be a consequence of it being the only one having no `style="color: red"` that is having a higher priority than simple css rules.

Comment: @PaulStrobach - I think you are right about something wrong with basic css, but am unable to figure out where. I have added style="color:red" also now. I have created a small jsfiddle to illustrate what is happening. Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Comment: Hello, when using this page the icon does not disappear but the text is just consisting of a big capital T. If the missing text is your problem, my answer should help you.

Comment: @PaulStrobach - ya, if i try your solution in the fiddle, it works, but in my browser it was invisible. Thanks a ton, this means there is something wrong somewhere else. Will check that out. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an closing `</i>` in your code line. If you place it at the end it wouldn't work either as the tooltip's text would be unreadable. You have to do something like this:

```
    <span class="tooltip"><i class="material-icons" ng-click="view(application._id)" >receipt</i><span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Paul

---

PS: It is working at my PC. I created a fiddle for it. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBQboL. I were not able to include the icon font but the icon is not disappearing.

Comment: The icon disappears. Although, am able to click it and if i hover on or around the area, it is not showing anything

Comment: Can it be that there is a style assigned that gives it eg. white font on white bg?

Comment: I dont think so, because the css that is related to this class is what i have shown, i have edited the question to mark that.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use Title="Tooltip Text" inside the i tag or any element like img. It's easier ^_^

Comment: you mean this : <i class="material-icons tooltip" ng-click="view(application._id)" Title="Tooltip Text">receipt</i>&nbsp;&nbsp; this didn't work. same problem, the icon disappears

Answer (score 2):

Hei man! I'll try to answer You as easily as possible

> You don't need a new class for tooltip effect

---

**HTML :**

```
I'm using Font Awesome Framework, like as Your

<body>

    ... HTML CONTENT ...

    <i class="fa fa-facebook">
        <span>My beautiful tootip</span>
    </i>

    ... OTHER HTML CONTENT ...

</body>
```

---

**CSS :**

```
i {
    position: relative; /** ADD THIS TO i TAG. This do magic! It's necessary **/
}

i span {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:  0;
    position: absolute; /** It's necessary to do magic **/
    bottom: -32px; /** Show Tooltip 32px bottom "i" tag. Depends on "i" tag height =) **/
    left: 0;
    text-align: center; /** If You want tooltip text centered **/
    padding: 5px; /** Tooltip padding **/
    width: 150px; /** Tooltip width. You can set 100% to cover all "i" tag **/
    height: auto; /** Auto is good choice **/
    background: #000; /** Tooltip background **/
    color: #fff; /** Tooltip text color **/
}

i:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

### ADDITIONAL - Perfect! But I want a beautiful animation (transition). How I can do it?

Add to above CSS code, this lines

```
i span {
    
    /** ... OTHER RULES SEE ABOVE ... **/

    transition-duration: 0.2s; /** Animation duration **/
    transition-property: opacity; /** Apply animation only on opacity rule **/
    
    /** Compatibility with other Browsers */
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
}
```

Comment: He is not using font awesome but Google Material Icons (material.io/icons).

Comment: I know. It's the same =)

Answer (score 1):

place **Span** inside **i** tag

**You have problem in this**

```
 <i class="material-icons tooltip" ng-click="view(application._id)" >receipt</i><span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

**Solution**

```
  <i class="material-icons tooltip" ng-click="view(application._id)" >receipt<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Hello, this wont work as then the tooltip text will be written in the tooltip font and not shown properly.

Comment: The icon disappears. probably because of the css but i am not sure. I am still able to click though

Comment: let me check it again

Comment: here is the video of the working tooltip on your html

https://www.screencast.com/t/4t9ATyVId

Comment: Thanks, this made me narrow down the problem, it works if I don't include a style sheet for the icon, but if I include the icon, it is still going away. Trying to figure that out.